# C - Float Imprecision, How to lock the decimal places for calculations?

Tags: c, math, numbers, precision, floating-accuracy

I was making a little program to test floats in the C: The program itself is very simple, I just want to based on the User's input, return how much `Dollar(s), Quarter(s)... etc`, his number has.

```
//------------------------------> First Part: All the necessary Variables <-----------------------------
 
int main (void)
{
    //Getting the user Input
    float number = get_float("Number: ");
   
    //Checking if is a positive number
    if (number < 0)
    {
        printf("A positive number, Please: ");
    }

    //Declaring my Constant/Temporary variables.
    float coinValues[] = {1.00, 0.25, 0.10, 0.5, 0.01};
    char  *coinNames[] = {"Dollar(s): ", "Quarter(s): ", "Dime(s): ", "Nickel(s): ", "Penny(ies): "};
    int   i            = 0;
    int   tmp          = 0;
    
//-----------------------------------> Second Part: The code Itself <-----------------------------------

    //Checking/Printing the necessary coins.
    while (number > 0)
    {
        //Until the loop stops, check if the number can be divided by the CoinValue.
        if (number >= coinValues[i])
        {
            //Print the current Coin Name from the divided value.
            printf("%s", coinNames[i]);
            //Check if the Current Number still contains Coin Values inside of it, if True counts one in your "Coin Score".
            while (number >= coinValues[i])
            {
                number -= coinValues[i];
                tmp++;
            }
            //Print the Current "Coin Score", then resets TMP.
            printf("%i\n", tmp);
            tmp = 0;

        }
        else
        {   
            //Updating the Coin value
            i++;
        }

    }
    
}
```

My program was running very well as long I use ***Integers***, but when I converted this code for ***Floats*** the values `(Dime(s), Nickel(s), and Penny(ies))` start to return **non-expected** results in the ***Int*** variable **tmp**.

An expected result for a number like **2.6**, will be **2 Dollars**, **2 Quarters**, **and 1 Dime**, but sometimes, instead of use the **Dime(s)**, the program skips them entire and make the operation with the **Nickel(s)**, however, what is bugging me is that the program is always returning **AWL=+** without any value and then the program stay froze forever.

Considering that my only thought is that I'm "suffering" from **Float Imprecision**, and I don't know how to solve it, so can anyone Help me?

***Ps.*** The program needs to always return the **maximum value** from each **coin** before pass forward.

Comment: The natural way to begin with is a to use a type with higher precision, like `double`. After that it really depends on your requirements, and how precise your calculations really need to be.

Comment: As for the problem of money, don't use floating point calculations. Convert all money into the smallest monetary unit (like for dollars, use cents) and then you can use integer arithmetic and don't loose precision or get rounding errors. So for the example of $2.60, that would be 260 cents.

Comment: Finally regarding the coin-change problem: I recommend you think about *division*. For example what is `260 / 100` (truncated to an integer)? What is `60 / 25` (again truncated to an integer)?

Comment: Values like `0.1` and `0.01` *cannot* be represented exactly in binary floating point, and any calculation with them will have some error in it.  Like SPD says, for currency use integers scaled to the smallest unit (with US currency, either cents (1/100 dollar) or mils (1/1000 dollar)).

Comment: Aside from working with integers, it is also possible to work with exact decimal or rational types. A web search should find some resources.

Comment: *My program was running very well as long I use Integers, but when I converted this code for Floats the values start to return non-expected results.* So there's a clear conclusion: use integers; don't use floats!  (Seriously.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is designed to **approximate** real-number arithmetic. IEEE 754-2008 says “Floating-point arithmetic is a systematic approximation of real arithmetic…” So there is no way to “lock” decimal digits in binary floating-point. It is intended to be used where you **want** an approximation, such as modeling physics. That even includes some financial applications, such as options evaluation. Although floating-point arithmetic can be used for exact calculations in some situations, these require particular care and are generally only pursued in special circumstances.

So the answer to your question on how to lock decimal places is there is no good way to do that with binary floating-point. Attempting to do so generally just yields the same effects as integer arithmetic but less efficiently and with more difficult code. So use integer arithmetic and scale the amounts according to the smallest unit of currency desired, such as a penny.